# Find the number of coefficients not divisible by k in the expansion of $(x^k+1)^n, n\ge 1,$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, modular-arithmetic

> Find the number of coefficients not divisible by k in the expansion of $(x^k+1)^n, n\ge 1,$ where k is an arbitrary positive integer greater than 1.

I know that modulo 2, $(x^2 + 1)^{2^i} \equiv x^{2^i} + 1.$ So for $x^2 + 1,$ it might be useful to write $n$ in binary and then compute the product of the corresponding terms modulo 2. But the question is slightly different; we may need to consider n in base $k$. If $k$ were prime, then we would have for an integer $i\ge 0$ that $(x^k + 1)^{k^i}\equiv x^{k^{i+1}} + 1\mod k.$ So if we write $n = a_m k^m + a_{m-1} k^{m-1} +\cdots + a_0 , a_i = 0,1,\cdots, k-1,$ then $(x^k + 1)^n\equiv (x^{k^{m+1}} + 1)^{a_m} \cdots (x^k + 1)^{a_0}$. Note that for $a < k, (x^{k^i} + 1)^a = \sum_{j=0}^a {a\choose j} x^{jk^{i}}$, so none of the coefficients are divisible by k. There are $a+1$ coefficients, all of which are nonzero. Also since k is prime, base k representations are unique. So each term in the product has a unique exponent, since each term corresponds to a selection of $m+1$ terms, one from each $(x^{k^i} + 1)^{a_i}$ term. Each such term contributes a unique power of $k$ that's multiplied by a number less than k and hence the resulting number of coefficients not divisible by k is $\prod_{i=0}^m (a_i + 1).$ But if k is composite, the problem seems harder.

Comment: is the exponent $n$ or $k^n$ ? Your writing as of now is very confusing.

Comment: The exponent is $n$. Can you tell me what's so confusing about my writing? At least when $k$ is prime, I'm pretty sure my answer is correct.

Comment: I see. I think it's simpler to deal with $\binom{n}{i}\pmod k$ directly. Only interesting cases are when $n<k.$

Comment: Is $x$ an integer or a real? Please clarify!